# convert from a string into a date in php

Tags: php, sql, string, date

I have looked around but keep getting an error.

I have the following string:

```
$date = "25 Jan 2013 07:30 PM";
```

but I need to add it into sql as separate date and time fields.  Any suggestions how I can convert it to a date rather than a string?  When I try to using something like

```
strtotime($date);
```

I end up with:

```
1359142200
```

Comment: Why do you have it written as `$date = "25 Jan 2013 07:30 PM";` in the first place?

Comment: What you end up with is a timestamp. Look into PHP's `date()` function for formatting.

Comment: @aguyfromhere it was coming from a csv report

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("25 Jan 2013 07:30 PM"));
$time = date("H:i:s", strtotime("25 Jan 2013 07:30 PM"));
```

Option 2

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat("j M Y H:i A", "25 Jan 2013 07:30 PM");
$date = $datetime->format("Y-m-d");
$time = $datetime->format("H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

For best results, convert `$date` to a `DateTime` object with [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and then use [`DateTime::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to get the values for your separate fields.

Example:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d M Y H:i A", "25 Jan 2013 07:30 PM");

$date = $dt->format("Y-m-d");
$time = $dt->format("H:i:s");
```

Answer (score -1):

So you just want them separated? Something like:

```
$year_month_day = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($date));
$timestamp = date('H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score -1):

If you want it as a timestamp then `strtotime()` is the PHP function to use:-
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

If you want it in a MySQL date format string then `strtotime()` in combination with `date()` would be the answer like this:-

```
$db_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date) );
```